# SWIG: How to map an enum to integer without %including the header?

Tags: swig

I have two swig modules that share some common headers. I only want to %include the header in one but I want the other to be able to still treat the enums as integers (rather than classes) without fully %including it. Something kind of like this:

MyEnum.h

```
typedef enum {
  One,
  Two
} MyEnum;
```

LibOne.i

```
module() libOne
%{
#include "MyEnum.h"
%}
%include "MyEnum.h"
```

HeaderUsingMyEnum.h

```
#include <MyEnum.h>

MyEnum DoSomething(MyEnum &anEnum);
MyEnum &DoAnotherThing(MyEnum *anEnum);
```

LibTwo.i

```
module() libTwo
%{
#include "MyEnum.h"
#include "HeaderUsingMyEnum.h"
%}
%include "HeaderUsingMyEnum.h"
```

The problem is that swig then turns around and creates swig objects in LibTwo whereas LibOne just automatically treats the enums as unsigned ints. Then I have a mismatch between the two modules on what they think a MyEnum is.

Obviously simply %including MyEnum.h in libTwo works perfectly well but it's a lot of duplication. I also know I can write a bunch of MyEnum typemaps for LibTwo but I want to know if there is an 'automatic' way to do it, maybe with %apply or some such thing?

There are quite a few enumerated types in the main library and I'd love to have a simply way to just tell SWIG to just treat them as ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I've been struggling to solve esoteric SWIG problems and didn't recognize when one came along that was actually simple. This seems to do the trick.

```
%include "typemaps.i"

%apply unsigned int { MyEnum };
```